# How can I convert if else code into json (or other) format?

Tags: python, if-statement

Consider this (arbitrary example, python syntax) code:

```
number = 42
name = 'arthur'

if number != 42:
    if name == 'arthur':
        number = 42
else
    if name == 'zaphod':
        number = 0
```

I want to convert it somehow into some kind of format so it can be kept as a file.
My initial thought is using `json`, but this is not a concrete requirement.

My thought is that the above code would translate into something like:

```
{'number':
    {'42':
        ['name': {'zaphod':0}],
     'other': 
         ['name':{'arthur':42}]
    }
}
```

Basically saying that at the end of process, the `if`-`else` rationale could be read from a file and by navigating the json the proper result would be found (if it exists).

I'm looking to see if there is any known way to do this or some documentation on an easy way to go.

Thanks

Comment: Why not keep it as Python and import?

Comment: What if you stored it as a .py file of some sort ;). Really though want is the rational for serialization here ?

Comment: I agree with the above comments, however in your example you would need to use an array of objects for each condition so that order is preserved  when deserialized. It's also best practice to store all significant data as *values*, and to keep keys as descriptors for those values.

Comment: Putting in a comment, because this is not a complete answer: Try `ast` module. Something like: `res = ast.parse(open("your/file/path").read())`. Then you could get things like: `res.body[2].test.comparators[0].n` == 42. I haven't worked extensively with this module. I went on doing `dir(..)` on the res hierarchy. May be you will be able to translate this into JSON. Going in the other direction should be relatively easier. Good luck :)

Comment: @zondo, the idea is that I can keep the logic in one file and then retrieve it  for different uses from one source.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after hierarchical data storage...

It might be worth looking into [XML and XPaths](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp), just to have a think about your situation, and get familiar with some concepts.

It would be possible to do this with JSON as well, using something like [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) - but I'd recommend having a play with XML/XPaths first, as it's a little more clear and is a more mature technology.

---

This is a demo of the sort of thing I had in mind:

`text.xml`:

```xml
<root>
    <condition var_name="number" op="not-equal" value="42">
        <condition var_name="name" op="equal" value="arthur">
            <result var_name="number" value="42"/>
        </condition>
    </condition>
    <condition op="default">
        <condition var_name="name" op="equal" value="zaphod">
            <result var_name="number" value="0"/>
        </condition>
    </condition>
</root>
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pprint import pprint
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# the <conditional> operations
ops = {
    'equal': lambda data, var_name, value: data[var_name] == value,
    'not-equal': lambda data, var_name, value: data[var_name] != value,
}

def el_get(el, attr_name):
    value = el.get(attr_name)
    try:
        value = int(value) # try to force numerics for the demo...
    except:
        pass
    return value

def dig(root, data):
    # get any results, and apply them to the data
    for el in root.findall('./result[@var_name][@value]'):
        var_name = el_get(el, 'var_name')
        value = el_get(el, 'value')

        if var_name not in data:
            raise Exception('bad var_name (%s)' % ( var_name ))

        data[var_name] = value

    # run through the conditions, running with the first that matches
    for el in root.findall('./condition[@var_name][@op][@value]'):
        op = el_get(el, 'op')

        if op not in ops:
            raise Exception('bad operation (%s)' % ( op ))

        var_name = el_get(el, 'var_name')
        value = el_get(el, 'value')

        if var_name not in data:
            raise Exception('bad var_name (%s)' % ( var_name ))

        result = ops[op](data, var_name, value)

        if result is True:
            dig(el, data)
            return

    # run through the defaults, taking the first
    for el in root.findall('./condition[@op="default"]'):
        dig(el, data)
        return

    return

# grab the XML
root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()

# process & print
data = { 'number': 21, 'name': 'arthur' }
dig(root, data)
pprint(data) # pass

# process & print
data = { 'number': 21, 'name': 'zaphod' }
dig(root, data)
pprint(data) # pass

# process & print
data = { 'number': 42, 'name': 'arthur' }
dig(root, data)
pprint(data) # pass

# process & print
data = { 'number': 42, 'name': 'zaphod' }
dig(root, data)
pprint(data) # pass
```

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I've implemented a demo